# set helper grey text for UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i set a default text in the search bar that looks grey so that it may hint what you could search before the user touches the search bar so that he may write something?

For example, i could have "Search for coffee shops or restaurants" and when i touch the UISearchBar the text dissapears ?

Comment: you can use Placeholder property of UISearchBar...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try Placeholder property of UISearchBar...and set it as `Search for coffee shops or restaurants`

Happy coding..